# Was "Rice Rice Baby" a Weird Al Yankovic song?

Tags: parody, weird-al-yankovic

I remember hearing the parody song ["Rice Rice Baby"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvX9UbhFaUg) on the radio in the early 1990s, back when Vanilla Ice's "Ice Ice Baby" was getting a lot of airplay.  I always wondered who did that song.

Doing a Google search, most web sites attribute the song to Weird Al Yankovic.  On YouTube, the top hits for "Rice Rice Baby" say it is a Weird Al Yankovic song.

I did find a couple of web sites that say it is not a Weird Al Yankovic song, but they provide no citations to support that claim.  Also, I noticed the song is not mentioned on this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic) listing all of his songs.

Was "Rice Rice Baby" a Weird Al Yankovic song, or was it a song by someone else?  Is there any authoritative source that provides the answer?

Comment: Why the downvote? I know about the [Meta discussion](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/37/58) about "identify this artist" questions, but this specific question has a lot of value since tons of people out there mistakenly think "Rice Rice Baby" is a Weird Al Yankovic song: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=%22weird+al+yankovic%22+%22rice+rice+baby%22

Comment: I'll explain my downvote.  First, it's not that popular.  Second, it could be answered on the first page of a Google search.  Third, since it's a self-answer question which is so easily answerable, it's pointless.

Comment: @JohnnyBones 1) Why is popularity relevant? 2) I don't see harm on expanding already existing answers through Q&As, and having the question here leaves the door open for other answers, with the potential of new details, quotes, sources, etc. 3) Why is self-answer relevant?

Comment: @JohnnyBones The top 3 hits on Youtube for "Rice Rice Baby" have combined for over 1.2 million views, so I don't think it's accurate to say it's not that popular.  Plus all 3 mention Weird Al, so my question is far from useless.  Also, that one link on the first page of Google search results looks like an amateurish page with no citations.  My answer provides a citation to Mark Jonathan Davis's official web site.

Comment: Vote to close because if we allow this "identify-this-artist" question we'll have to allow them all.

Comment: No matter if the song is popular or not, asking a question without proper research is not wanted. That is one of the cornerstones of the StackExchange network.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Since I answered my own question, some of my research is contained in the answer.  Also, I've seen plenty of well-received unresearched questions on SE ([this one](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/25112/is-it-perfectly-legal-to-walk-topless-in-new-york-city) immediately comes to mind).

Comment: Yes, I understand that you have spent some time researching the answer. However the rule is to NOT post a question unless you have done a reasonable amount of research and NOT found an answer. I this case you have actually found an answer. So why ask the question at all? But I am not a judge, but a humble user of several SE sites.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson StackExchange "explicitly encourages" people to ask and answer their own questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this question. Several of the first hits for the title of the track alone reference Yankovic, so it's a common misunderstanding. There's no concern about clutter, as Stack Exchange privileges new and unanswered questions, so this will recede, but, if as has shown to be the case with other Stack Exchange sites, may rise to have good Google prominence and therefore help dispel the misunderstanding.  I guess in short, I'm an inclusionist. If someone were continually self-answering to the point of rep-whoring, I might feel differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, "Rice Rice Baby" is not a Weird Al Yankovic song.  The song was produced by Mark Jonathan Davis.  On his [official web site](http://www.markjonathandavis.com/), it says:

> In 1990, [Davis] moved to Los Angeles to manage the Premiere Radio Comedy Networks, where he produced parody songs including "The Star Wars Cantina," "Jeannie's Diner," and "Rice Rice Baby."

Another [web site](http://mich.ideatown.com/mdemento.html) maintained by Davis says that Gary Thomas was the rapper in the song and Davis was the deejay and backup shouter:

> In November of 1990, rapper Vanilla Ice's hit "Ice Ice Baby" became the vehicle for MJD's first big solo hit Rice Rice Baby.  Gary Thomas was the rapper, while MJD was the deejay (and backup shouter); MJD also played the Yamaha PSS-480 keyboard koto over the 12"-instrumental music track.  Within weeks of its national release on the Premiere Radio Networks, this Chinese food homage ranked number one at KIIS-FM/Los Angeles and other radio stations around the country.  It even appeared in a HIDEOUSLY produced music video on Rick Dees "Into The Night"!

Answer (score -1):

There are two completely different songs called 'Rice Rice Baby. One is by a supposed North American rapper. The other is by a supposedly Asian wrapper.
Here is the one by the North American rapper:

I can't find the Asian version, but sample lyrics included:

"I go crazy when I hear smoke alarm"